# SQL query with UNION refinement

Tags: sql, oracle11g, union

I would like to know if there is a better way to code the below requirement:
I am using Oracle 11.x db

Table setup:

```
create table S_ASSET (ROW_ID varchar2(10), X_QUOTE_ID varchar2(10), SP_NUM varchar2(10), AMT number(10), ASSET_NUM varchar2(10));
create table S_QUOTE_ITEM (ROW_ID varchar2(10), AMT number(10));
create table S_QUOTE_ITEM_XM (PAR_ROW_ID varchar2(10), AMT number(10));
```

Table 1-

```
insert into S_ASSET (ROW_ID, X_QUOTE_ID, SP_NUM, AMT, ASSET_NUM) values ('1', 'A1', '000', 10, 'AAA');
insert into S_ASSET (ROW_ID, X_QUOTE_ID, SP_NUM, AMT, ASSET_NUM) values ('1', 'A2', '000', 20, 'AAA');
insert into S_ASSET (ROW_ID, X_QUOTE_ID, SP_NUM, AMT, ASSET_NUM) values ('2', 'B1', '111', '', 'BBB');
insert into S_ASSET (ROW_ID, X_QUOTE_ID, SP_NUM, AMT, ASSET_NUM) values ('3', 'C1', '222', 10, 'CCC');
insert into S_ASSET (ROW_ID, X_QUOTE_ID, SP_NUM, AMT, ASSET_NUM) values ('3', 'C2', '222', 0, 'CCC');
insert into S_ASSET (ROW_ID, X_QUOTE_ID, SP_NUM, AMT, ASSET_NUM) values ('4', 'D1', '333', 10, 'DDD');
insert into S_ASSET (ROW_ID, X_QUOTE_ID, SP_NUM, AMT, ASSET_NUM) values ('5', 'E1', '444', 0, 'EEE');
```

Table 2-

```
insert into S_QUOTE_ITEM (ROW_ID, AMT) values ('A1', 5);
insert into S_QUOTE_ITEM (ROW_ID, AMT) values ('A2', '');
insert into S_QUOTE_ITEM (ROW_ID, AMT) values ('B1', 0);
insert into S_QUOTE_ITEM (ROW_ID, AMT) values ('C1', 5);
insert into S_QUOTE_ITEM (ROW_ID, AMT) values ('C2', 0);
insert into S_QUOTE_ITEM (ROW_ID, AMT) values ('D1', '');
insert into S_QUOTE_ITEM (ROW_ID, AMT) values ('E1', 5);
```

Table 3-

```
insert into S_QUOTE_ITEM_XM (PAR_ROW_ID, AMT) values ('A1', 1);
insert into S_QUOTE_ITEM_XM (PAR_ROW_ID, AMT) values ('A1', '');
insert into S_QUOTE_ITEM_XM (PAR_ROW_ID, AMT) values ('B1', 1);
```

where x-quote_id (of Table 1)=row_id (of Table 2)=par_row_id (of Table 3)

I need the sum of AMT columns grouped by sp_num. Below is the query which I have written. I am looking for a shorter more efficient way to write the same.

```
select sp_num, sum(amt) as DocFee
from
(   
    (
        select x_quote_id row_id, amt, sp_num
        from s_asset
    )
    union
    (   
        select a.row_id, a.amt, b.sp_num
        from
        (   
            select row_id, sum(amt) amt
            from s_quote_item
            group by row_id
        ) a,
        s_asset b
        where b.x_quote_id = a.row_id
    )
    union      
    (
        select a.par_row_id row_id, a.amt, b.sp_num
        from
        (
            select par_row_id, sum(amt) amt
            from s_quote_item_xm
            group by par_row_id
        ) a,
        s_asset b
        where b.x_quote_id = a.par_row_id
    )
)
group by sp_num 
order by sp_num
```

Expected O/P:

```
sp_num    DocFee
000       36
111       1
222       15
333       10
444       5
```

Thanks to all who came up with their efficient solutions. I am however struggling to combine below queries (owing to the fact that I am completely new SQL), all of which are having a common factor sp_num

Query 1: (Parent)

```
select  POL.SP_NUM POL#
,       POL.ASSET_NUM COV#
,       sum(POL.AMT) SI
from S_ASSET POL
group by
        POL.ASSET_NUM
,        POL.SP_NUM
order by POL.sp_num
```

Query 2: (GP)

```
select 
  sp_num as pol#,
  coalesce(sum(
    (
      select sum(deb.amt)
      from s_invoice deb
      where deb.fn_accnt_id = pol.row_id
      and deb.debit_type = 'Customer' 
    )
  ), 0) -
  coalesce(sum(
    (
      select sum(cred.amt) 
      from s_src_payment cred
       where cred.asset_id = pol.row_id
      and cred.cg_dedn_type_cd = 'Customer' 
    )), 0)
   as gp
from s_asset pol 
group by sp_num
order by sp_num
```

Query 3: (DOCFEE) (either the below or the result shared by Juan Carlos in this thread)

```
select sp_num, sum(amt) as docfee
from ((select a.sp_num, a.amt as amt
       from s_asset a
      ) union all
      (select a.sp_num, q.amt as amt
       from s_asset a join
        s_quote_item q
            on q.row_id = a.x_quote_id
      ) union all
      (select a.sp_num, x.amt as amt
       from s_asset a join
            s_quote_item_xm x
            on x.par_row_id = a.x_quote_id
      )
     ) aqx
group by sp_num
order by sp_num;
```

Comment: using Oracle 11.x....hoping you could spare a few min and help me out the some more stuff, the same I have appended to this thread

Comment: In this case, is better if you create a new question and link to this one. Also I dont see what is the expected output of your new request. And I dont see the schema for the new tables. You also could create the schema in http://sqlfiddle.com/ that provide a nice tool to make/test the querys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/75c05/24)**

```
WITH A as (
     SELECT sp_num, X_QUOTE_ID, sum(AMT) AMT
     FROM S_ASSET
     GROUP BY sp_num, X_QUOTE_ID
), B as (
     SELECT ROW_ID, sum(AMT) AMT
     FROM S_QUOTE_ITEM
     GROUP BY ROW_ID
), C as (
     SELECT PAR_ROW_ID, sum(AMT) AMT
     FROM S_QUOTE_ITEM_XM
     GROUP BY PAR_ROW_ID  
)
SELECT sp_num, COALESCE(SUM(A.AMT),0) + 
               COALESCE(SUM(B.AMT),0) + 
               COALESCE(SUM(C.AMT),0) DOCFEE
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
       ON A.X_QUOTE_ID = B.ROW_ID
LEFT JOIN C
       ON A.X_QUOTE_ID = C.PAR_ROW_ID
GROUP BY sp_num     
ORDER BY sp_num;
```

Comment: Thank You Juan Carlos. I am bit intimidated by the "Join" concept...hence avoid it as much as possible. But I will keep it in mind while trying to complete my code. It just comes to prove that there are more than one way to write an SQL query. You could let me know; if I were to combine this query with 2 others both of which are having sp_num as a common factor, how would you go about with it... I have appended the thread with the other queries above...thanks again

Comment: well you can see I already did that here. I join `A` with `B` and `C`. I like more the cte notation because is easy to read. Also is easy if you split your problem is small pieces and then join it together

Comment: @AnnaJoel . . . Is this faster in your case than the aggregation approach in my answer?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know is a small sample, but I put original solution and our both answer on the sqlFiddle. So can check the explain plan.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is best to aggregate each of the subtables at thelevel of `sp_num` and then do a final aggregation:

```
select sp_num, sum(amt)
from ((select a.sp_num, sum(a.amt) as amt
       from s_asset a
       group by a.sp_num
      ) union all
      (select a.sp_num, sum(q.amt) as amt
       from s_asset a join
            s_quote_item q
            on q.row_id = a.x_quote_id
       group by a.sp_num
      ) union all
      (select a.sp_num, sum(x.amt) as amt
       from s_asset a join
            s_quote_item_xm x
            on x.par_row_id = a.x_quote_id
       group by a.sp_num
      )
     ) aqx
group by sp_num;
```

If you like, you can shorted the query by removing the first level of aggregations:

```
select sp_num, sum(amt)
from ((select a.sp_num, a.amt as amt
       from s_asset a
      ) union all
      (select a.sp_num, q.amt as amt
       from s_asset a join
            s_quote_item q
            on q.row_id = a.x_quote_id
      ) union all
      (select a.sp_num, x.amt as amt
       from s_asset a join
            s_quote_item_xm x
            on x.par_row_id = a.x_quote_id
      )
     ) aqx
group by sp_num;
```

My guess is that Oracle will produce a better execution plan for the first version, under most circumstances.

Comment: Thank u Gordon, I'm not familiar with Oracles ways of execution, it just wanted to reduce the lines of code and ensure bext performance.